# Is "Christmas Eve" taking place after "Peace Talks"/"Battle Grounds"?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Long awaited 16th part of the "Dresden Files" series - "Peace talks" is out and the immediate followup (most likely taking place the same night) "Battle Ground" is coming soon. However, on 24-12-2018 Jim published a short story "[Christmas Eve](https://www.jim-butcher.com/christmas-eve)".

What has surprised me was this fragment:

> I've opened the envelope.  It had one piece of paper in it.  On it was written a very large number.
>  “What is this?” I asked. 
> “The total of everyone’s medical bills from last summer,” Molly said, her voice quieter, soberer.  “Everyone who got hurt.  It’s all paid for.” 
> **I didn’t want to think about the peace talks. Pain.  So much pain.** 
> “What about the funerals?” I asked.  My voice was bitter. 
> Molly was quiet for a long moment before she said, gently, “Those too.”

So is "Christmas Eve" taking place after the still unpublished "Battle Grounds"?

Comment: the original public plan was to publish PT/BG as one book. that was still the official word when the xmas story was released. plus, the phrase "last summer" makes it seem likely the xmas story was well after the end of BG.

Comment: Note that (not really a spoiler), "Christmas Eve" is included as a prologue to *Battle Grounds* (though there seem to be places here and there where it wasn't edited to match exactly with the final published version).

Comment: ("Christmas Eve" is an epilogue, not a prologue, to *Battle Grounds*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official Jim Butcher timeline, yes.

https://www.jim-butcher.com/timeline

> 14 ASF: Monsters, the short story from Parallel Worlds.
>
> 14 ASF, July: Peace Talks and Battle Ground
>
> 14 ASF, December 24th: Christmas Eve, a short story.

*ASF: After *Storm Front*